# literature on eigendecomposition of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

About a month ago I posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32843/eigen-decomposition-of-an-interesting-matrix-general-case) about eigendecomposition of a special matrix; and I received an answer. This is not my main field of study and I came to this as part of the proof for a method I developed to address a bioinformatics problem. Now I am interested to learn more about this area. Could anyone suggest some references and relevant literature that I can read.
Moreover, I may end up publishing my method. How should I acknowledge and cite the stackexchange users/website ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people study eigendecomposition from theoretical interest, some from numerical interest. I guess you study this from theoretical interest. 
I would like to introduce you the SVD of companion matrices, for example this paper
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X05005007
It is very interesting considering the exact decomposition of special matrices.

If you know the name (rather than nick name) of the solver, you may mention him in your paper. In many cases, people here just share their problem or solution with others and do not ask for such credit.